# How to remove a failed DC from AD?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain, controller

- We have two redundant domain controller servers of Win server 2003(server1 , server2) .
- Recently server1 got crashed (Complete Harddisk failure)
- Inserted new harddisk, Imported Acronics image backup of server2 into server1.
- Changed the IP address of server1 => OK
- Trying to change the name of Server => throwing error messagethat name is already available
- Guess need to remove the Server1 name from AD.
- when trying to remove using DCPROMO => throwing error message(not able to remove from AD)
  **" I want rename to server1, with all the AD configurations intact(client machines) and to work both server in redundant mode  "** 
  Kindly suggest me how to proceed on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

First, you failed here:

> Inserted new harddisk, Imported Acronics image backup of server2 into server1.

DON'T DO THAT. Get a Windows 2003 installation CD and install from scratch. Join it to the domain with a completely new name. Then promote it to a domain controller.

Once you've done that, you can follow these steps: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216498